# abel's test proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

can someone verify following proof of abel's theorem

> **Abel's convergence theorem** :  If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges and  $(b_n)$ is monotonic convergent sequence then
>   $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$ converges

we know that by summation by parts we have that $\sum_{j=m+1}^n a_j b_j  = A_n b_{n+1} - A_mb_{m+1} + \sum_{j=m+1}^n A_j (b_i - b_{i+1})$ where $A_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$

we will prove this by cauchy crtierion for convergence of series

so we have to show that $\forall \epsilon>0 \,\, \exists N \,\, \in \mathbb{N} \,\, \forall n > m \geq N \,\,|\sum_{j=m+1}^n a_jb_j| < \epsilon$

- $= |\sum_{j=m+1}^n a_jb_j|$
- $ \leq |A_n b_{n+1} - A_m b_{m+1}| + \sum_{j=m+1}^n |A_j||b_i - b_{i+1}|$
- key point is that $(A_nb_{n+1})$ is convergent sequence cause it is product of two convergent sequences
- now by cauchy criterion for convergence of sequences we have that there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N} \,\, \forall n > m \geq N |A_{n}b_{n+1} - A_{m}b_{m+1}| < \epsilon/2$
- now for other term $\sum_{j=m+1}^n |A_j||b_i - b_{i+1}| \leq M \sum_{j=m+1}^n |b_i - b_{i+1}| = |b_{n+1} - b_{m+1}|$ where $M$  is upper bound for partial sums of $\sum_{n}a_n$ and sum simplifies due to montonicity
- which we can apply cauchy criterion for convergence of sequences we have $\exists N_2  \in \mathbb{N} \,\, \forall n>m\geq N \,\, |b_{n} - b_{m}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$
- our required $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$

Is there any flaw in above proof ? thanks in advance

Comment: Would it maybe be easier to use that a) all but finitely many $b_i$ have the same sign and b) the $b_i$ are uniformly bounded

Comment: (1) get rid of the bullet points. (2) introduce notations *before* you start using them, not afterwords (and you never define $(y_i)$). (3) don't split inequalities over bullets (why is there an = sign on the LHS side? You don't have anything for it to equal).

Comment: (4) slip a comma in after $\forall n > m \ge N$. (5) $M$ needs to be an upper bound on $|A_j|$, not $A_j$ (6) you could simplify the next bit by proving the whole result for an increasing sequence only, then noting that if $(b_i)$ is decreasing, then $(-b_i)$ is increasing - a very minor bit of algebra handles the decreasing case. (7) None of these are actual logic issues, though. That appears to be alright. But please work on improving your clarity. It will help not only your readers, but yourself.